How to run a powershell script using elevated permissions in Ansible Automation Platform
I am trying to run a powershell command which has to be run with admin privileges on a large number of Windows servers.
I need to use Ansible Automation Platform and I will be using a machine credential which is a member of the administrators group for all the Windows servers.
Below are the tasks I am trying to run:
``
tasks:
- name: Check if SMB v1 is enabled
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol
  register: smbcheck

- name: Disable SMBv1 only on servers where it is enabled.
  ansible.windows.win_powershell:
    script: |
      Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB1Protocol $false
  when: smbcheck.output

``
The first task runs fine but no changes are made when running the second task. When I manually run the powershell script on the server it will only run if I open powershell as admin.
I have tried adding become: true and become_method: runas, but that fails with the following error:
“No setting was provided for required configuration plugin_type: become plugin: runas setting: become_user”
I have updated the machine credential in AAP so the “Privilege Escalation Method” is runas, but this fails with the same error method.
Other articles I have found indicate that I need to add become_user with {{ ansible_user_name }} but I do not know how to add this to my playbook if I am using a machine credential.
I know there is a windows feature module which can uninstall SMBv1 but this results in a restart, whereas the powershell script just disables SMBv1 without restarting the servers.
Any ideas how to solve this?
Thanks
